# undefined method Crypt_Rc4::enableContinuousBuffer()

Tags: php, phpseclib

I need to transfer some xml files via sftp to another server.

I tried to get phpseclib running for like 4 hours. Composer *crashed* several times trying to install phpseclib, so i downloaded it manually.

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib');
require('phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php');
```

I can't get around this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Crypt_Rc4::enableContinuousBuffer() in           
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php
on line 1640
```

I tried to track down if there are some classes which override some parent classes of Crypt_TripleDES (object on line 1640), but I did not find anything. All other classes in this project are written by me.

Edit:

Problem could be tracked down to the PHP class /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/Crypt/Rc4.php
My unsatisfying but working solution is renaming the file to _Rc4.php. But I need an another solution since I don't have too much influence on the productive server.

Comment: To diagnose the crashing of Composer can you post the error? As for the Fatal error you got when you tried installing phpseclib manually...  do you perchance have PEAR installed? Perchance do you have PEAR's Crypt_Rc4 installed? If so then that'd be the problem.

Comment: Well yes it kind of is installed. I went to /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/Crypt and renamed Rc4.php to _Rx4.php and ist working now. But that is not a solution i'm pleased with. My application needs to run on a server I don't have to much influence on the configuration.
Composer crashed cause of memory limit, which I increased to 1GB, but Composer somehow just uses 512MB. Can't get composer to use more memory.

Comment: You could use the namespace'd php5 branch: https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/archive/php5.zip

Comment: that's good. No more conflict :)
But I now get a class not found: Fatal error: Class 'phpseclib\Math\BigInteger' not found in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php on line 1378
I only exchanged the phpseclib folder, I did not "use phpseclib" or any kind of namespace for phpseclib. Do i need to "use" a namespace? and what is its name?

Comment: Actually, it looks like phpseclib's php5 branch is only partially namespaced, so it wouldn't work. I guess you could add namespacing yourself to phpseclib. Should be as simple as adding `namespace phpseclib` to each file and then doing `use phpseclib` at the top of your script.

Comment: unfortunately that is not working either. i just hope i can convince our server admin to take care of that.